# How do I enable Bluetooth on my Nikon D7500?

Tags: snapbridge, nikon-d7500

On my Nikon D7500, the Bluetooth menu is not available and returns the message "This option is not available at current settings". From other answers I assume you have to first connect Wi-Fi to the nearest broadband. Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Or any tips on how to turn on Bluetooth to allow connection to SnapBridge? Many thanks. Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn on the Bluetooth on my Snapbridge-enabled Nikon DLSR?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88778/how-do-i-turn-on-the-bluetooth-on-my-snapbridge-enabled-nikon-dlsr)

Answer (score 3):

It’s your iPhone, not SnapBridge. Go to your iPhone settings. Select Bluetooth, and click on the “i” next to your camera's name. Then click on “forget this device”. Now try pairing your camera throught SnapBridge. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to again reinstal snapbridge on your smartphone. I had the same problem and this worked.

Comment: have the sameproblem. reinstalling snapbridge did not work for me

Comment: Thanks for the help. I deleted the SnapBridge software and then reinstalled it and this did the trick. It re-connected to my camera and the Bluetooth function is now operating. Thanks for the help

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled the app as stated above and now it works fine. I can see what the camera sees on my iPad. You can use iPad as a remote. You can even change the ISO, Aperture and shutter speed from iPad. Don't give up when it works it's awesome.
Touringt